# Requesting a date throws and error with a GROUP command

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I looked up a few of answers but what I read did not make sense to me. I want to get the order date in the column but it gives me an error when I include it. "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column."

```
SELECT COUNT(`style`) AS `c`,`order_date`, `style` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `order_date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY style
```

It works fine if I leave off the `order_date`.

```
SELECT COUNT(`style`) AS `c`, `style` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `order_date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY style
```

What I trying to do is I want how many styles were sold between the date. I want to know who many of each style and the total of all sales.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: If you have multiple order dates with the same style, which date should it show in the result?

Comment: I am using 5.7.26